# Smart contracts: is every public function payable?

Tags: transactions, payable

I am aware of the `payable` annotation on the public methods. But just want to make things more clear:

1. is every public function payable? Even without the `payable` annotation?
2. what would happen if a private function is annotated as `payable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. is every public function payable? Even without the payable annotation?

No.

> 2. what would happen if a private function is annotated as payable?

You would get a syntax error from the compiler.